# about caste system

Tags: caste-system

In Gita there is also caste system. May be it was for the stability of the society. My question : A son of a sudra may have potential to become a bramhin.( I mean to say that he may have more brain capacity and may contribute more to Hinduism by writing some philosophy). So wasn't it unfair for that sudra's son? I think this is a waste of talent. I also think god also don't want that, that is why caste system is not rigid nowadays.

Comment: Hi Santanu.. yes, you are correct that birth ALONE does not determine what he will become. but our karmas in previous birth make us take this birth in a family whose varna most suited to our gunas. To go against that is possible, but will take LOT of effort and tapas. it is not required for society either, in fact, it makes things worse if everyone wants to change their varna, whether shudra becoming brahmin or brahmin becoming shudra. as long as everyone follows their own varna dharma, society will prosper

Comment: Yes. Varna change can be possible in this very birth. Scriptures describe many methods and have many examples.

Comment: Can you attach some link supporting your comment @The Destroyer !

Comment: @SantanuDebnath See questions linked and search questions under [tag:caste-system].

Comment: Hi, Varna in Bhagavad Gita is ascribed by birth but is based on qualities and actions, not blood. This is further supported by Yudishtir son of Dharmaraj in the Tirtha Yantra Parva section CLIXXIX and Narada also mentions something similar in LXXXIII

Comment: Wisdom Library is a good source